# Any way to craft crimson altars when they have all been destroyed?

Tags: terraria

My SO was thourough when they broke the crimson altars.

Only to realise way later that I need one to build the 'deer thing'.

Is there a way to still craft demon altar things when they are destroyed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you destroy all of them, you can't craft things that requires Crimson Altars anymore.

But you can always load into another world to craft things. The characters carry over from world to world.

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraria/comments/feivn0/what_happens_if_i_destroy_each_and_every_single/).

Comment: It should be mentioned that a world editor can also be used to place a crimson altar into the world again. While it is very much considered cheating, it is much more comfortable than regularly switching worlds and basically a requirement if playing multiplayer.